# Evaluation order of a function makeSum in haskell

Tags: haskell, evaluation

I am a Haskell newbie and i am looking at evaluation order as part of my lectures of University. I have an example that i can't quite work out.
I know that Haskell uses lazy evaluation and that it evaluates outermost, leftmost.
In this case i think it is the function itself that i don't understand.

c) Show all the steps in the evaluation of makeSum [3, 2, 7], using the following deﬁnition of makeSum and foldr1.

```
makeSum [] = 0
makeSum xs = foldr1 add xs
where
add x y = x + y

foldr1 f [x] = x
foldr1 f (x:xs) = f x (foldr1 f xs)
```

I get that foldr1 takes a function and a list and if the list contains one element it returns the element and if the list is longer it applies the function to the first and the rest of the elements.

makeSum takes an empty list and returns zero and here is where i get confused. If it has a case where it takes an empty list shouldn't the recursive call look like this:

```
makeSum (x:xs) = foldr1 add xs
```

rather than this:

```
makeSum xs = foldr1 add xs
```

From what i am getting makeSum takes a list and adds the elements in it together?

How do i evaluate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
makeSum [] = 0
makeSum xs = foldr1 add xs
   where
   add x y = x + y
```

is equivalent to the OP's alternative

```
makeSum [] = 0
makeSum (x:xs) = foldr1 add (x:xs)
   where
   add x y = x + y
```

The point is: in the first snippet, the variable `xs` will be bound the *whole* list. Also, `xs` is non empty because the first line handles the `[]` case.

There is no need to match the other constuctor `_:_` explicitly, a catch-all pattern as `xs` does the same job, in this case.

Comment: Right, got it! Thanks a lot, i was struggling to understand why we are able to only use xs.

Answer (score 3):

> How do i evaluate this?

So, you just have to expand carefully your code there, given the definitions:

```
makeSum [3, 2, 7]               --initial definition
foldr1 add [3, 2, 7]            --substitute with makeSum xs = foldr1 add xs, being xs = [3,2,7]
add 3 (foldr1 add [2, 7])       --foldr1 f (x:xs) = f x (foldr1 f xs) being f = add and xs = [2,3,7]
add 3 (add 2 (foldr1 add [7]))  --keep the recursive work
add 3 (add 2 (7))
3 + ((2 + 7)
3 + 9
12                              --final result
```